# Angular Two way binding working wrongly on my form list?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, two-way-binding

I have a list of persons That I bonded two ways to a form using a for each,
everything works fine, but when I want to bind the person's array of emails, it does not work!!
it sets the same value toall the other persons in my list!

Here is my code:

it works fine for the firstName element, but not for the email

```
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Prénom</label><span>*</span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required [(ngModel)]="listGlobalBeneficiaries[i].firstName"
                              [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" id="bfirstName"
                              name="{{i}}_bfirstName" #bfirstName="ngModel">
                            <div [hidden]="bfirstName.valid || bfirstName.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                              Prénom est obligatoire
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div> 


<input _ngcontent-fsl-c265="" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required="" id="bfirstName" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="1_bfirstName" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="name">



                        <div class="col-md-4" >
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>E-mail</label><span>*</span>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" email
                              required [(ngModel)]="listGlobalBeneficiaries[i].emails![0].address"
                              [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control"
                              name="{{i}}_emailaddress" id="{{i}}_emailaddress" #emailaddress="ngModel">
                            <div [hidden]="emailaddress.valid || emailaddress.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                              E-mail est obligatoire
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>


<input _ngcontent-qhm-c265="" type="email" placeholder="Email" email="" required="" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-touched" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-email="" ng-reflect-name="2_emailaddress" id="2_emailaddress" ng-reflect-model="" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]">
```

Comment: `listGlobalBeneficiaries[i].emails![0].address"` it contains a 0 instead of `i` as in the names, maybe that ?

Comment: Nope, that is not it, `i` represents the index `<div *ngFor="let benf of listGlobalBeneficiaries; let i = index">`, I think because am binding an element that is inside a list that is inside another list, but why exactly I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the problem was that when initializing the emails array.

Previous:

```
this.listGlobalBeneficiaries[i].emails = this.init_emails;
```

Fix:

```
this.listGlobalBeneficiaries[i].emails = [
                        {
                          type: 'WORK',
                          stillPrimary: true,
                          valid: true,
                          address: '',
                        },
                      ];
```

because objects are assigned and copied by reference in typescript